# How do i shrink an image horizontally using CGAffineTransform?

Tags: objective-c

I've been using CABasicAnimation to move around images. Now I need to take a view and shrink it horizontally. On the web I see some people using CGAffineTransform to shrink/grow images proportionally. I need the view to shrink **horizontally** ONLY. See image below:

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[`CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sx,sy)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeScale) will do the work.

```
  CGAffineTransform a = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 1.0);
  editingView.transform = a;
```

You can use [`[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a); if you want it to be animated.

```
CGAffineTransform a = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 1.0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{  
                    editingView.transform = a;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    /* do something after the animation */
                 }];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Is there a sample that I can use as reference? Maybe a link or a simple example you can share?

Comment: Will the scaled image just appear or will it be a gradual shrink like when using CABasicAnimation? I want the user to be able to see the image shrinking.

Comment: @user3071579 For animation use `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:]`.

Comment: I have implemented your original code but the image doesn't change? Here's my code: ....................................                                                                                        - (void)scaleImage{
    CGAffineTransform a = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
    scrollFlat.transform = a;
}

Comment: @user3071579 I would advice you to check if the `scrollFlat` in this method is referring to the UIView you want to transform.

Comment: Will this work for a UIImageView too or just a UIView?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48290/discussion-between-user3071579-and-arch)

Comment: @user3071579 The class UIImageView is inherited from UIView so UIImageView objects are generally UIView objects.